# Include root element in Swagger JSON sample

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, swagger

In our REST API we support both XML and JSON as input/output format and while generating Swagger documentation the sample input generated by Swagger is not showing Root Node value for JSON input but it's coming for XML sample.

As our REST API expecting root node for for JSON also, how can I make Swagger to show Root Node in sample?

Swagger sample XML -

```
<Request>
    <EmployeeNumber>string</EmployeeNumber>
    <Department>
            <DepartmentId>string</DepartmentId>
            <DepartmentName>string</DepartmentName>
            <DepartmentHead>string</DepartmentHead>
            <DepartmentLocation>string</DepartmentLocation>
    </Department>
</Request>
```

Swagger sample JSON -

```
{
    "EmployeeNumber": "string",
    "Department": {
      "DepartmentId": "string",
      "DepartmentName": "string",
      "DepartmentHead": "string",
      "DepartmentLocation": "string"
    }
  }
```

Expected JSON sample -

```
{
  "Request": {
    "EmployeeNumber": "string",
    "Department": {
      "DepartmentId": "string",
      "DepartmentName": "string",
      "DepartmentHead": "string",
      "DepartmentLocation": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

How to provide example sample in swagger annotations instead of automatically generating one?

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Could not find any solution, so wrote some quick and dirty tool which loops over model and adds this property

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with openApi swagger. I've fixed it by adding a OpenApiCustomiser :

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser addCustomOpenAPI() {
    return (OpenAPI openApi) -> {
        Map<String, Schema> definitions = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
        definitions.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            Schema schema = e.getValue();
            Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromSchema(schema, definitions);
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
            Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
            String finalExample = new StringBuilder().append("{\"").append(e.getKey())
                    .append("\":").append(Json.pretty(example)).append("}").toString();
            schema.setExample(finalExample);
            openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().put(e.getKey(), schema);
        });
    };
}
```

Maven dependency for the ExampleBuilder :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the result is just fantastic, I got exactly what I needed. If you are using swagger , I suggest you to move to OpenApi.

```
{
"UserDTO": {
  "userId": "string",
  "userName": "string",
  "login": "string",
  "password": "string"
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations

Have a look at this. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it didn't provide any information about how to include RootNode in JSON sample generated by Swagger UI. @ApiModel property is already used and it's working for XML sample but not for JSON

Comment: I am also facing same issue. did you guys found solution for this?