# JSON parent/root element missing from response when using Swagger Annotations

Tags: java, spring, maven, jackson, swagger

This is a Spring boot application, where as I mentioned in subject "appConfig" root element is missing from the response when I added Swagger. Any Help on this forum will be appreciated.

Here is my response object class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "appConfig")
public class AppConfig {
// Using lombok for getter setters
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty("toggles")
    private List<Toggle> toggles;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty("resources")
    private List<Resource> resources;
```

This is my restController

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/appConfig", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public AppConfig appConfig() {
        final AppConfig appConfig =delegate.getAppConfig();
        return appConfig;
    }
```

This is what I am getting in the response

```
//MISSING appConfig root element !!!!  
{
"resources": [
    {
      "lastUpdateTimeStamp": "string",
      "resourceName": "string"
    }
  ],
  "toggles": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "state": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my POM dependency for Swagger:

```
<!-- Swagger dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is my Swagger Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()       
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build()
          .apiInfo(apiInfo());                                           
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
          "Blah", 
          "Blah", 
          "Blah", 
          "Terms of service", 
          new Contact("Blah Administrator", "URL", "Email"), 
          "License of API", "API license URL");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Work around which is UGLY! is define a Dummy response object and wrap your response inside it. So Swagger strips that off and gives the answer what is expected. Still looking for an answer!

Comment: Same problem. @user3836681 did you find more elegant way?

Comment: @TornikeT see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Enable these properties at your ObjectMapper configuration:

```
jsonObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
jsonObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, got same result, please see me case if you can help

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, before using swagger i had response CustomResponse class with getter and setters:

```
public class CustomResponse<T> { 
    private T data;
    private String message;
}
```

and response looked liked this:

```
{
  "CustomResponse" : {
    "data" : {
      "prop" : "prop",
      "prop 1" : "prop1",
    },
    "message" : "true",       
  }
}
```

after implementing swagger result is like this:

```
{
    "data" : {
      "prop" : "prop",
      "prop 1" : "prop1",
    },
    "message" : "true"
  }
```

tried to add @JsonRootName("CustomResponse") but result is same.

here is swagger config:

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
   return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(CustomResponse.class))
            .genericModelSubstitutes(CustomResponse.class)
            .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();

}
```

also tried @amseager solution:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

    return mapper;
}
```

is there any way that to return response with root name.

Comment: Have you added @JsonRootName("CustomResponse") and object mapper flags at the same time?

Comment: yes i have both same time, now added, response fixed but now swagger doesn't works,   No mapping for GET /myapp/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

/myapp/swagger-resources/configuration/ui    works.

  @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        converters.add(messageConverter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

Comment: I'm not sure about .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(CustomResponse.class)). Try to play with swagger config

Comment: Also pls post @Api annotation that's on your controller

Comment: not using any @Api annotaions in controllers,  tried ApiResponse annotation with response class but result was same

Comment: Try to add @Api(value = "YourController", tags = "YourController") onto controller class (with replacing "YourController")

Comment: still same result, just found this https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/swagger-contract-tests/src/main/java/springfox/test/contract/swagger/listeners/ObjectMapperEventListener.java
will try to implement

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues using OpenApi Swagger , I've fixed it by adding a OpenApiCustomiser.
To avoid duplicated answer , I posted the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649066/include-root-element-in-swagger-json-sample/73610590#73610590)